# Does rosjava have explicit support for hot class reloading?

Tags: ros, gradle, dependencies, rosjava, java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to have dynamic dependencies in rosjava, but it is not working.

rosjava can have jar-files as dependencies, but what if a jar-file gets recompiled while my rosjava node is still running? Does rosjava have explicit support for hot class reloading? Or do I have to add this myself, for example by using JRebel? (or a similar plugin?)

If such support already exist in rosjava, how do I use this? I tried to set the "changing"-parameter in my Gradle build-file to true for my jar dependency (which is on my local filesystem), it gives no errors, but my node still uses the old dependency from before recompilation instead of the newly compiled jar-file. So this is not enough and more needs to be done.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65983/does-rosjava-have-explicit-support-for-hot-class-reloading?/) by [PJvG](https://answers.ros.org/users/4985/pjvg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also sent an email to Damon Kohler with this issue..

He replied with:

> "There are no peculiarities to the way
> rosjava is configured with Gradle. I
> suggest asking on the Gradle support
> forum."

Well I did ask at the Gradle forums before I posted this question.

Anyway, my best guess is there is no support at the moment, and if you want hot class reloading in rosjava you'll have to figure it out yourself, either by using a plugin or by programming it yourself.

---

Originally posted by [PJvG](https://answers.ros.org/users/4985/pjvg/) with karma: 31 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0